# appending text to specific line in file bash

Tags: bash, sed

So I have a file that contains some lines of text separated by ','. I want to create a script that counts how much parts a line has and if the line contains 16 parts i want to add a new one. So far its working great. The only thing that is not working is appending the ',' at the end. See my example below:

**Original file:**

```
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
```

**Expected result:**

```
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,xx
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,xx
```

**This is my code:**

```
            while read p; do
                if [[ $p == "HEA"* ]]
                then
                    IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$p"
                    echo ${#ADDR[@]}
                    arrayCount=${#ADDR[@]}
                    if [ "${arrayCount}" -eq 16 ];
                    then
                        sed -i "/$p/ s/\$/,xx/g" $f 
                    fi
                fi
            done <$f
```

**Result:**

```
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
,xx
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
,xx
```

What im doing wrong? I'm sure its something small but i cant find it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using awk:

```
awk -F, 'NF==16{$0 = $0 FS "xx"} 1' file
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,xx
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
b,b,b,b,b,b
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,xx
```

- `-F,` sets input field separator as comma
- `NF==16` is the condition that says execute block inside `{` and `}` if # of fields is 16
- `$0 = $0 FS "xx"` appends `xx` at end of line
- `1` is the default awk action that means print the output

Comment: Just tested this and the result is not right. This is the result:
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,xxa,a,a,a,a

Comment: I have copy/pasted actual output in my answer and isn't it matching with your expected output?

Comment: Most likely you have DOS line ending `\r` in your input. Just run `dos2unix` before running this awk command.

Comment: Ah yea that was the problem. Is dos2unix a default command? On my side I get: dos2unix: command not found.

Comment: @FlorianSchaal just `apt-get install dos2unix` or `yum install dos2unix` it.

Comment: Or use this gnu awk command to take care of `\r`: **`wk -F, -v RS='\r\n' 'NF==16{$0 = $0 FS "xx"} 1' file`**

Answer (score 1):

For using sed answer should be in the following:

1. Use `${line_number} s/..../..../` format - to target a specific line, you need to find out the line number first.
2. Use the special char `&` to denote the matched string

The sed statement should look like the following:

```
sed -i "${line_number}s/.*/&xx/"
```

I would prefer to leave it to you to play around with it but if you would prefer i can give you a full working sample.